Смешение знаков при прямой речи
У Розенталя есть правило:

Если прямая речь находится внутри слов автора, то перед ней ставится
двоеточие, а после нее — или запятая, или тире, или запятая и тире (по
условиям контекста)

Однако это правило как-то однобоко воспроизведено. Так, непонятно, снимают ли дополнительный знак - запятую (даже если он требуется по условиям контекста) многоточие, вопросительный знак и восклицательный.
Анализирую этот пример:

И только когда он шептал: «Мама! Мама!» — ему становилось как будто
легче (Ч.) — тире после вопросительного/восклицательного знака,
которым заканчивается прямая речь;

По условиям контекста здесь требуется запятая после прямой речи, так как это СП, но запятая не стоит, ставится только тире.

Возьмем пример из текста Овчинниковой:

Из района в район, из дома в дом передавали как пароль: «Собраться в
назначенный час...», и по улицам осаждённого города двигались дети...

Здесь автор ставит запятую, потому что она требуется по условиям контекста (СП), но не ставит тире, хотя есть многоточие. И что это? Ошибка?

Непонятно, каким правилом руководствоваться в том случае, когда на постановку знака влияет контекст?

Вопрос 1. Так, непонятно, снимают ли дополнительный знак - запятую (даже если он требуется по условиям контекста) многоточие, вопросительный знак и восклицательный.
Нельзя говорить, что запятую "снимают".
Посмотрите еще раз (§ 51. Прямая речь внутри слов автора):
пункт первый — ставится только запятая;
пункт второй — ставится только тире;
пункт третий — запятая и тире (для двух реплик).
В ПАС под ред. Лопатина говорится то же самое:

§ 136. Если прямая речь оказывается внутри слов автора, то она заключается в кавычки, а перед ней ставится двоеточие; прямая речь начинается с прописной буквы. После прямой речи знаки препинания расставляются следующим образом:
а) запятая ставится, если она была необходима в месте разрыва вводящих слов автора: Сказав: «До скорой встречи», она быстро вышла из комнаты;
б) тире ставится в случае отсутствия знака препинания на месте разрыва вводящих слов автора: Перебарывая неловкость, он пробормотал студенческую остроту: «У меня бабушка корью заболела» — и хотел придать начатому разговору непринужденную легковесность (Бонд.);
в) тире ставится, если прямая речь заканчивается многоточием, вопросительным или восклицательным знаком: Дети ожидали, что он похвалит их, но дедушка, покачав головой, сказал: «Этот камень лежит здесь много лет, здесь ему место...» — и рассказал о подвиге трех советских разведчиков (Сух.); Петр Михайлыч хотел сказать: «Не впутывайся ты, пожалуйста, не в свои дела!» — но промолчал (Ч.); Она [собака] останавливается. Я повторяю: «Что сказано?» — и держу ее долго на стойке (Пришв.)...

Вопрос 2. Возьмем пример из текста Овчинниковой:
Из района в район, из дома в дом передавали как пароль: «Собраться в назначенный час...», и по улицам осаждённого города двигались дети...
Для начала предположу, что это, собственно, не текст самой Людмилы Овчинниковой, потому что везде написано: (По Л. Овчинниковой) (см.).
Похоже, что предложение писательницы было сокращено или перестроено для учебных целей.
И сделано это неудачно, да ещё и с ошибкой (если прямая речь находится внутри слов автора и заканчивается многоточием, то после нее ставится тире).
Правильно:
...передавали как пароль: «Собраться в назначенный час...» — и по улицам...
